# Is this n-body problem O(n^2) or O(n log n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm writing an article on the n-body problem, and I'd like to be technically accurate.

The code is [here](https://github.com/MichaelJCole/n-body-wasm-canvas/blob/dev/src/assembly/nBodyForces.ts#L91).  And here are the comments and loops:

```
/**
 * Given N bodies with mass, in a 3d space, calculate the forces of gravity to be applied to each body.  
 * 
 * This function is exported to JavaScript, so only takes/returns numbers and arrays.
 * For N bodies, pass and array of 4N values (x,y,z,mass) and expect a 3N array of forces (x,y,z)
 * Those forcess can be applied to the bodies mass to update the its position in the simulation.
 * Calculate the 3-vector each unique pair of bodies applies to each other.
 * 
 *   0 1 2 3 4 5
 * 0   x x x x x
 * 1     x x x x
 * 2       x x x
 * 3         x x
 * 4           x
 * 5
 * 
 * Sum those forces together into an array of 3-vector x,y,z forces
 * 
 * Return 0 on success
 */

 // For all bodies:

  for (let i: i32 = 0; i < numBodies; i++) {                   // TypeScript.  i32 is type 32bit int
    // Given body i: pair with every body[j] where j > i
    for (let j: i32 = i + 1; j < numBodies; j++) {             // is this "n" or "log n"?
      // Calculate the force the bodies apply to one another
      stuff = stuff
    }
  }
  return stuff
```

I'm fairly certain the algorithm is > O(n) and <= O(n*n).

By [process of elimination](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/) that leaves O(n log n) as the other option.

Looking at the grid, I think O(1/2 n^2) = O(n^2)

Looking at the loops, I think the inner loop is `< n`, but I'm not sure if it's all the way to `log n`.

If I'm looping through n, what does adding a `log n` inner loop look like?  If not an inner loop, an outer loop?

Comment: it's n+(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+..1  = (n*n) -(1+2+...+n)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407714/big-o-how-to-determine-runtime-for-a-for-loop-incrementation-based-on-outer-for/41410929#41410929

Comment: *This algorithm* has a quadratic time complexity, but it is not the best you can do for the N-body problem

Comment: It's the only algorithm with machine precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Calculate the force the bodies apply to one another` is an O(1) operation then what you have is the following summation.

[image]